# BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper alternative, to avoid setTargetType/setPrototypeBeanName

Tags: spring-batch

I need a way to get rid of `fieldSetMapper.setTargetType` because I do not want to add a POJO every time I have a new file to read. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Springbatch has a few `FieldSetMapper` implementations available out-of-the-box : [Documentation (FieldSetMapper)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/FieldSetMapper.html)

You can for example use a `PassThroughFieldSetMapper` to get a `FieldSet` object in your processor. You can do the same with an `ArrayFieldSetMapper` to get an array object.

But in your case, I think you need to implement your own `FieldSetMapper`. It could for example have a `names` property (with a setter) and a `targetClass` property (with a setter). Using [Reflect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html), you could then cast the object to your desired class and call setters according to the names passed as arguments.

Here's what a FieldSetMapper looks like :

```
@Override
public Report mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {

    T object;
    object.setField(fieldSet.readString(0));
    return object;
}
```

Here's what Reflect looks like :

```
    Method method = object.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
    method.invoke(object);
```

Comment: I have updated the question, actually I need to get rid of fieldSetMapper.setTargetType because I do not want to keep adding new POJOs

Comment: @explorer `setTargetType` method only belongs `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper`, so you can get rid of it using any other (even a custom one) `FieldSetMapper`.